# How to drawing a decision tree?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

This is my script for a decision tree in R:

```
    library(caret)
    library(rpart.plot)
    library(plyr)
    library(dplyr)
    
    data("iris")
    
    names(iris) = tolower(names(iris))
    
    table(iris$species)
    suppressMessages(library(caret))
    
    index = createDataPartition(y=iris$species, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
    
    train = iris[index,]
    test = iris[-index,]
    
    trainctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, verboseIter = FALSE)

dt.model <- train(species~., data=train, method = "rpart", 
                  tuneLength = 10,
                  preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                  trControl = trainctrl,
                  metric="Kappa")

dt.predict <-predict(dt.model, test)
confusionMatrix(dt.predict, test$species)
```

How can I make the tree drawing with nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in R `plot` function to get a simple drawing of your decision tree using the `finalModel` attribute:

```
plot(dt.model$finalModel)
text(dt.model$finalModel)
```

[image]

In addition, you can also use the `rattle` package to get a more visually appealing drawing of the decision tree:

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, but I have this error when I run the code with my database:
> plot(dt.model$finalModel)
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
> text(dt.model$finalModel)
Error in rpartco(x) : no information available on parameters from previous call to plot()

Comment: is there another way to know which characteristics the model considers more important?